# hide a button from a specific product Tag in Woocommerce product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I have Woocommerce WebSite. I need a php code to hide part of html in product details page by a certain Product Tag.

For example if product include "abc" product tag, then hide an html button.
I need this code for product details page only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with Wordpress **`has_term()`** conditional function for the `'product_tag'` custom taxonomy, like in this example:

```
// Output some code except for "abc" product tag
if( ! has_term( 'abc', 'product_tag', get_the_id() ) ){
    ?>
    <a href="#">This product has not "abc" tag</a>
    <?php
}
```

The button will be hidden from products that have "abc" product tag…